# How do you solve a logarithm with a non-integer base?

Tags: logarithms, irrational-numbers, fractions

How would one calculate the log of a number where the base isn't an integer (in particular, an irrational number)? For example:

$$0.5^x = 8 \textrm{ (where } x = -3\textrm{)}$$

$$\log_{0.5}8 = -3$$

How would you solve this, and how would this work for an irrational base (like $\sqrt{2}$)?

Comment: You can switch to the natural logarithm and use Taylor series.

Comment: Note that there's nothing scary about non-integer bases for logarithms: the natural logarithms are base $e$, which is not just non-integer or even just irrational but transcendental!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's rewrite this in a different way:
$$
0.5^x=8
$$
Take the logarithm with respect to *any* base $a$ ($a>0$, $a\ne1$):
$$
\log_a(0.5^x)=\log_a8
$$
which becomes
$$
x\log_a 0.5=\log_a 8
$$
or
$$
x=\frac{\log_a 8}{\log_a 0.5}
$$
You would stop here weren't from the fact that $8=2^3$ and $0.5=2^{-1}$, so
$$
x=\frac{\log_a 8}{\log_a 0.5}=\frac{\log_a 2^3}{\log_a 2^{-1}}=
\frac{3\log_a 2}{-\log_a 2}=-3
$$
You need to compute no logarithm, actually.

Comment: "You need to compute no logarithm, actually." +1, "with respect to any base" +1 again if I could

Answer (score 7):

This is the base changing formula : 
$$\log_{a}(x) = \frac{\log_{b}(x)}{\log_{b}(a)}$$

Answer (score 2):

rewrite your equation in the form $2^{-x}=2^{3}$

Comment: how does this help with a non-rational base?

Comment: give another example please

Answer (score 1):

Yet another attempt to help. Let’s look at a somewhat different case. How do you calculate $\log_{3.8}(8)$? Again as egreg says, rewrite as $3.8^x=8$, take the (ordinary) log of both sides to get $x\log_{10}(3.8)=\log_{10}(8)$, and $x=\log_{10}(8)/\log_{10}(3.8)$

If you want $\log_{\sqrt2}(8)$, it’s the same thing, only you can shortcut matters early: $8={\sqrt2\,}^x=(2^{1/2})^x=2^{x/2}$; knowing that $8=2^3$, you see that $x=6$, $\log_{\sqrt2}(8)=6$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use natural logarithms, because for all $a$ and $b$ : $\log_a(b)=\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)}$.

Comment: "... for all $a$ and ...": Don't you need, at the very least, $a\ne 1$ (as well as $a>0$)?